# Auto-play video and images with RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

I have implemented auto-play video and images simultaneously in `RecyclerView` from web services. But I got some error and warning when scrolling the RecyclerView.

This is my log error and warnings:

```
BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-0-7717-41] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-0-7717-41] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-0-7717-41] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-0-7717-41] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-0-7717-41] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-0-7717-41] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-0-7717-41] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-0-7717-41] connect: BufferQueue has been abandoned
GLConsumer: [SurfaceTexture-0-7717-41] detachFromContext: abandoned GLConsumer
OpenGLRenderer: Failed to detach SurfaceTexture from context -19
/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: env->IsInstanceOf fails
MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
MediaPlayer: Couldn't open https://dev-cdn.wahhao.com/onboard/user_88889/post/7207_1541756144.mp4: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: https://dev-cdn.wahhao.com/onboard/user_88889/post/7207_1541756144.mp4
MediaPlayer: info/warning (3, 0)
```

Comment: From review: could you post your code as well?

Comment: Hi, as answered by @ssdeno below, I'm author of the toro lib. If you can explain your goal I think my lib can help. A quick look can be found here: https://ene.im/2017/07/09/toro-101-how-to-1/ and/or here: https://github.com/eneim/toro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am use toro player for auto play in recyclerview. Simple library , i had no problem. Already toro player using the exo player

- library : [Toro player](https://github.com/eneim/toro)

  additional [Exo player](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer)

Answer (score 0):

Issue related to properly handling MediaPlayer lifecycle. Item in RecycleView destroyed but MediaPlayer object still alive. You must correctly handle MediaPlayer manually or use library like [VideoPlayerManager](https://github.com/danylovolokh/VideoPlayerManager)